# How to batch change registry values

Tags: windows-registry

I recently moved a program's folder from one drive to another. Going through the registry and changing all instances of `C:\MyProgram` to `D:\MyProgram` worked perfectly.

Now I want to do the same for another program's folder, but it has a *lot* of entries. Is there a way to change all of them at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not one of the most [programmatic approach](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) but should do what you want.

- Export the Registry key as `.REG` file and open it in a text editor
- Then do Find & Replace operation and save it

  [image]
- Import the registry